# Why subtract from 256 when assigning signed char to unsigned char in C++?

Tags: c++, char, twos-complement, bit-representation

in Bjarne's "The C++ Programming Language" book, the following piece of code on chars is given:

```
signed char sc = -140;
unsigned char uc = sc;
cout << uc // prints 't'
```

1Q) chars are 1byte (8 bits) in my hardware. what is the binary representation of `-140`? is it possible to represent -140 using 8 bits. I would think range is guaranteed to be at least [-127...127] when signed chars is considered. how is it even possible to represent -140 in 8 bits?

2Q) assume it's possible. why do we subtract `140` from `uc` when `sc` is assigned to `uc`? what is the logic behind this?

**EDIT:** I've wrote `cout << sizeof (signed char)` and it's produced 1 (1 byte). I put this to be exact on the byte-wise size of `signed char`.

**EDIT 2:** `cout << int {sc }` gives the output `116`. I don't understand what happens here?

Comment: A decent text-book should have contained information about things like [*two's complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is the most common way to handle signed integers.

Comment: Just a quick question: which edition of the book? There have been quite a few over the years.

Comment: @MSalters it's 4th edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Unless you're writing something very low-level that requires bit-representation manipulation - avoid writing this kind of code like the plague. It's hard to read, easy to get wrong, confusing, and often exhibits implementation-defined/undefined behavior.

To answer your question though:

The code assumed you're on a platform in which the types `signed char` and `unsigned char` have 8 bits (although theoretically they could have more). And that the hardware has ["two's complement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) behavior: The bit representation of the result of an arithmetic operation on an integer type with N bits is always modulo 2^N. That also specifies how the same bit-pattern is interpreted as signed or unsigned. Now, -140 modulo 2^8 is 116 (01110100), so that's the bit pattern `sc` will hold. Interpreted as a signed char (-128 through 127), this is still 116.

An `unsigned char` can represent `116` as well, so the second assignment results in 116 as well.

116 is the [ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com/) of the character `t`; and `std::cout` interprets `unsigned char` values (under 128) as ASCII codes. So, that's what gets printed.

Answer (score 1):

The result of assigning -140 to a `signed char` is implementation-defined, just like its range is (i.e. see the manual). A very common choice is to use wrap-around math: if it doesn't fit, add or subtract 256 (or the relevant max range) until it fits.

Since `sc` will have the value 116, and `uc` can also hold that value, that conversion is trivial. The unusual thing already happened when we assigned -140 to `sc`.